# Having issues running javascript on Visualstudio(MacOS) writing for webdevelopment?

Tags: javascript, macos, visual-studio

I'm learning to write javascript and here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html Public "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtmll/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Chapter 7: Example 1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function window_onload()
        {
            var numberForms = document.forms.length;
            var formindex;
            for (formIndex = 0; formIndex < numberForms; formIndex++}
            {
                alert(document.forms(formIndex).name);
        }
        ]
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="window_onload()">
    <form action="" name="form1">
        <p>
            This is inside form1.
        </p>
    </form>
    <form action="" name="form2">
        <p>
            This is inside form2
        </p>
    </form>
    <form action="" name="form3">
        <p>
            This is inside form3
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have saved the file as a .html, .js and a .htm and had no luck in getting it up and running when opening the browser and I'm looking for a reason why this has happened.

Answer (score 0):

You've got several syntax errors. In the `window_onload` function you have a `}` instead of a closing `)`.

There's also a random `]` at the very end of the function and your function is missing a closing `)`